# Changing Web Part properties via powershell

Tags: web-part, powershell, web

i am currently wanting to update the "ShowSortOptions" & "ShowLanguageOptions" via Powershell l have filter with the correct web part using

$Webpart = $WebPartManager.WebParts | Where { $_.Title -eq $TitleofWebPart}

I then use the following :

$Webpart.ShowSortOptions = "False"

$Webpart.ShowLanguageOptions = "False"

But the property doesn't change when l save the changes, but when l go manually to the web part and change it via that route it changes and when l view the property in PS it shows the updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `SaveChanges` method of the `WebPartManager`.  For example:

```
$Webpart = $WebPartManager.WebParts | Where { $_.Title -eq $TitleofWebPart}
$Webpart.ShowSortOptions = "False"
$Webpart.ShowLanguageOptions = "False"
$WebPartManager.SaveChanges($Webpart)
```

Comment: Hi Sorry yes l am doing that

Comment: Are you logging into the UI with a different account that you are executing powershell under?  If so, make sure the powershell account doesn't still have the page checked out.

Comment: Hi same account, l check out the page in PS $page.CheckOut() make the change then check back in and publish

Comment: Are there potentially "closed" webparts on the page with the same Title?

Comment: I have checked in the web part page maintenance and all web parts are "Open on Page" so no closed web parts

Comment: Instead of setting to a string `"False"`, set it the the Boolean `$false`

Comment: by running just $Webpart.ShowSortOptions.$false

Comment: `$webpart.ShowSortOptions = $false`

Comment: OMG that worked cheers Willman much appreciated ... :-)